# Jenkins Naginator plugin and regex

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Has anyone managed to get Jenkins Naginator plugin working with the use of a regex?

I have the console output

```
Build was aborted
Aborted by xxxxxxxxx
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level C:\xxxxxxxxx\workspace\testSuiteExecution\target\surefire-reports to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testSuiteExecution/builds/534/htmlreports/HTML_Report
ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:\xxxxxx\workspace\testSuiteExecution\target\surefire-reports' does not exist.
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: ABORTED
```

I use the naginator plugin to rebuild previous build only if the it was aborted.
Therefore I put :
[image]

But this isn't working. I tried many  regex variations (eg Build was aborted), but with no luck.
Has anyone managed to get it working?

Do you have any alternatives to re-run only an aborted build (not failed, or successful, or unstable)

Answer (score 3):

Just skip the slashes. the "regex" should be in this case:

```
Build was aborted
```

You can add an OR condition with

```
||
```

Just as an example:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' || .OutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax was changed.
Currently correct is:

```
first phrase|any second phrase|third text
```

Important point: absence of spaces near symbol "|".

This example:

```
first phrase | any text
```

means search for occurrence of "first phrase " or " any text".

Also I didn't find proper syntax for wildcards with "*" after huge amount of experiments, so it doesn't behave as regular expressions.